# My numerical to binary function is not producing an output

Tags: python

Does anybody have an idea why this function would not generate an output?

```
import math

def converter (value):
  list1 = []
  list1.reverse()  
  while value >= 0:
   Remainder = value%2
   list1.append(Remainder)
   value /= 2
   math.floor(value) 
  list1.reverse() 
  return list1

converter(17)
```

The model would not generate an output. After debugging I found the source of the problem `value /= 2` changing this to something like `value -=2` seem to enable the code to run, however, it is not the output I want.

Comment: `math.floor` doesn't do anything useful unless you assign it back to something

Comment: `while value >= 0` - when do you expect this condition to be false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple problems with your code. You want to change your condition in the while loop as it runs forever. Also, you need to change the the new assignment of the variable `value`:

```
import math

def converter (value):
    list1 = []
    while value > 0:
        remainder = value % 2
        list1.append(remainder)
        value = math.floor(value / 2) 
        
    list1.reverse()
    return list1

converter(17)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

**Edit:** I would also remove `math.floor()` by an integer division:

```
def converter (value):
    list1 = []
    while value > 0:
        remainder = value % 2
        list1.append(remainder)
        value = value // 2 
        
    list1.reverse()
    return list1

converter(18)
```

Answer (score 0):

just do the following changes and it'll work
1: change the loop condition from (while value>=0) to value>0
2: change the value/=2 to value//=2
It will work then.